# To show a hidden div with If-else condition for mobile quiz application

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, show-hide

What I want to do:
I am trying to create a mobile quiz application that could display a list of questions in a form one by one.

What I am able to do:
I have read through this site and am able to scroll through the questions without any problems. Also, the Javascript scoring engine is working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var currentQuestion=0;
    var totalQuestions=$('questions').size();   
    $questions = $('.questions');
    $questions.hide();
    $('.scorepage').hide();
    $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeIn(); //show the first question
    // when users click on the "Next question button...
    $('#next').click(function(){
      $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).fadeOut(function(){ //hide the current question
        currentQuestion = currentQuestion + 1; //go to next question
        if(currentQuestion == totalQuestions){ //if no more question        
          $('.scorepage').show();
          $('.button1').hide();                         
        }else{      
          $($questions.get(currentQuestion)).show(); //else display the current question
        }
       });
     });
   });
</script>
```

What is my current program structure:

The application begins with a form of n questions. Each question are framed using 
`<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="questions">` questions with radio button inputs `</div>`.

Following the question, there is a button, in which clicking on it will call the `getScore()` javascript. This section is framed as `<div class="scorepage">` button here and a textbox to display score`</div>`.

Finally, the navigation button is at the end of the form. It is framed as `<div class ="button1"></div>`

What is my problem?
Before answering any question, the scorepage is hidden. This is achieved by the `$('.scorepage').hide();`. 
However, I could not show the scorepage when there is no more question by using  `$('.scorepage').show();` and to hide the next button (Since there is no more question) by using `$('.button1').hide();`

Can anyone see where the mistake in my logic is?

Comment: First, check if you are sure to pass into if(currentQuestion == totalQuestions){ ... perhaps with an alert.

Comment: You are right.  if(currentQuestion == totalQuestions) doesn't have response even with alert(). However, else { alert()} works perfectly. Still looking into the problem. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Alright. I need to apology for wasting the resources. I just realized that I did not put a .questions in the var totalQuestions=$('questions').size(); I must thank girardengo for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count the number of questions, try to using jquery function lenght for counting elements:

```
var totalQuestions = $('.questions').length
```

his should work